# Multiple Loops to control on and off LEDs

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I'm new here. I have tried to write a simple code to turn LED's and light them up in specific pattern and being able to switch it off while in loop. So far I've managed to either get them constantly flashing in pattern and not responding to button or when I wrote in seperate void loops each function IDE Arduino throwing me error 'expected 'while' before 'loop1'' and I'm completely stuck and not got a clue what's the problem with code. Anyone could help?

Here's a code:

```
const int ledPin =  2;
const int ledPin1 = 3;
const int ledPin2 = 4;
const int buttonPin = 5;

int programState = 0;

int buttonState;
long buttonMillis = 0;
const long intervalButton = 300;   

long ledMillis = 300;
const long intervalLed = 500;   

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(ledPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin2, OUTPUT);    
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);     
  digitalWrite(buttonPin, HIGH);
}

void loop()
{
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

 if (buttonState == LOW && programState == 0)
  do{
   programState = 1;
    }
void loop1(){
if {programState = 1 && buttonState == HIGH}
 do  {
   programState = 2;
    ledMillis = currentMillis;
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin1,HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin2,HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin2,LOW);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin1,LOW);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin,HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin1,HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin2,HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin2,LOW);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin1,LOW);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW);
    delay(1500);}
 }
 void loop2(){
 if (programState = 2 && buttonState == LOW)

 do {
  programState = 2;
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin1,HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin2,HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin2,LOW);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin1,LOW);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin,HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin1,HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin2,HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin2,LOW);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin1,LOW);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW);
    delay(1500);}


 else if  (programState == 2 && buttonState == HIGH) 
 do
   {

    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledPin1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledPin2, LOW);
  }
}
yield();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `do` function wrongly:

Like this:

```
do{
  programState = 1;
}
```

It should be something like:

```
do
{
  programState = 1;
} while (`some condition`);
```

Where `some condition` is a condition that repeat the parts in { and } in case `some condition` is true.

However, besides that, it does not make sense normally to assign a variable in a while loop as only statement, since it will be 1 after the first iteration and reassigning it again does not make the value different (`programState` stays at 1).

Also note that in most cases the following form is used (unless you always want the body to be executed at least once):

```
while (`some condition`)
{
  `statements`
}
```

Are you sure you need the `do` or `while` statement at all? Otherwise, try to remove the `do` statements and see if that is closer to what you need (I cannot map the code to your requirements). I have the feeling you want to use loops to prevent a lot of code duplication, for that you need to store the `ledPin`, `ledPin1` and `ledPin2` variables in an array and loop over them.

Another way is instead of e.g. the following code:

```
digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
delay(200);
```

to create a separate function:

```
void setPin(int pin, int value)
{
   digitalWrite(pin, value);
   delay(200);
}
```

and call the function by:

```
setPin(ledPin, HIGH);
```

Now you can change all occurences of 'digitalWrite(`some pin`, `some state`); delay(200)' to the single statement above.

Also, I see there is a function `yield` that is not implemented.

Comment: Thank You :) I will follow Your advice and see where it takes me

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using the `do` construct incorrectly, you are also using an approach that won't work.

You generally should not use a do-while statement in Arduino. That causes your code to "stick" in the body of the do-while statement while the `while` condition is true, which prevents the rest of your code from executing.

You also should not use the `delay()` function if you need to manage timing different things at the same time. (To make a more general statement, you should not use the `delay()` function **at all**. Forget it exists.) There are rare cases (like doing one-time setup of hardware in your `setup()` method.) where using the `delay()` function is appropriate, or **very** short intervals like timing ultrasonic pulses, but the `delay()` function ALWAYS causes your program to come to a complete halt until the delay interval has passed.

You should search on "Arduino blink without delay" and study the example project you find. It outlines how to use the `millis()` function to keep track of timing. With that approach you can time multiple things at the same time. (You'd have multiple "fire time" variables that would remember the `millis()` value at which you want a change to occur, and you get that value of `millis()`, your code would trigger the change (toggling an LED, for example) and then update that "fire time" variable.